# How to make SVG Elements draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an HTML file that has SVG code in it like this:

```
<g id="node27" class="node"><title>blahblah</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="242" cy="-401" rx="58.5343" ry="58.8803"/>
<text text-anchor="start" x="213.5" y="-403.5" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="10.00">SVG Sample</text>
<text text-anchor="start" x="227" y="-393.5" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-size="10.00">Element</text>
</g>
```

I am trying to make this ellipse draggable. So far the most success I have is with CSS at the bottom of this page like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
.node:hover {
        fill: green
}
```

When I hover over this element, the text turns green. What I would really like to do is instead be able to drag this element around the page. Is there a drag CSS selector?

Comment: Give this [link](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/) a try. Hopefully, It will be helpful.

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work for me